# Cannot change the background of DropdownMenu

Tags: android, drop-down-menu, android-jetpack-compose, android-compose-dropdownmenu

I'm trying to follow [this tutorial](https://foso.github.io/Jetpack-Compose-Playground/material/dropdownmenu/)

But I need more customized UI regarding the dropdown list. I need to make the popup background rounded. But when I added `.clip(RoundedCornerShape(20))` into the `DropdownMenu`'s modifier, it still have the white background

[image]

Bellow is my test composable code:

```kotlin
@ExperimentalFoundationApi
@ExperimentalCoilApi
@Composable
fun TestScreen(
   navigator: AppNavigator,
) {
    var expanded by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    val items = listOf("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F")
    val disabledValue = "B"
    var selectedIndex by remember { mutableStateOf(0) }
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .background(Color.Cyan)
            .padding(top = 70.dp)
            .wrapContentSize(Alignment.TopStart)
    ) {
        Text(
            items[selectedIndex],
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .clickable(onClick = { expanded = true })
                .background(
                    Color.Gray
                )
        )
        DropdownMenu(
            expanded = expanded,
            onDismissRequest = { expanded = false },
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .clip(RoundedCornerShape(20))
                .background(
                    Color.Red
                )
        ) {
            items.forEachIndexed { index, s ->
                DropdownMenuItem(onClick = {
                    selectedIndex = index
                    expanded = false
                }) {
                    Text(text = s)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I can still clip, draw border, set background color. But the white background is just still there.

I tried to look into the source code of `DropDownMenu` but I can't seems to find the place for it. I'm new to Jetpack Compose, so maybe I missed something.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`DropdownMenu` looks like this [because](https://github.com/androidx/androidx/blob/4927325cde5001059d2ed17dd11ec0b929fb68dc/compose/material/material/src/commonMain/kotlin/androidx/compose/material/Menu.kt#L116) of default `Card` parameters.

You can change `MaterialTheme` related parameters for the whole app or override them for a single view like this:

```kotlin
MaterialTheme(
    colors = MaterialTheme.colors.copy(surface = Color.Red),
    shapes = MaterialTheme.shapes.copy(medium = RoundedCornerShape(20))
) {
    DropdownMenu(
        expanded = expanded,
        onDismissRequest = { expanded = false },
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
    ) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: @TranHoaiNam I've showed you where the `Card` is used inside `DropdownMenu`. This component has default parameters for shape and background color, which are taken from `MaterialTheme`. With my solution you're providing different values, same as you do in your theme, but in this case you can apply to only one composable instead of the whole app.

Comment: Duckhov, just one more "simple" question. The `Card` itself have the elevation value, but it's a private field inside the file you just showed me, can I somehow override that elevation?

Comment: @TranHoaiNam no, there's no easy way you can override this one. Ofc you always can copy full source code of `DropdownMenu` and change it.

Comment: The parameter `colors` of MaterialTheme is now called `colorScheme`.

Comment: It should be `extraSmall` instead of `medium` in my case

Answer (score 11):

```
implementation "androidx.compose.material3:material3:1.0.0-alpha16"
```

With the dependency above, you can change the DropdownMenu Background color with the `Modifier`

`modifier = Modifier.background(Color.Blue),`

```
@Composable
fun ListItemPopupMenu(
    menuItems: List<String>,
    onClickListeners: List<() -> Unit>,
    onDismiss: () -> Unit,
    showMenu: Boolean,
) {
    DropdownMenu(
        modifier = Modifier.background(Color.Blue),
        expanded = showMenu,
        onDismissRequest = { onDismiss() },
    ) {
        menuItems.forEachIndexed { index, item ->
            DropdownMenuItem(
                text = { Text(text = item) },
                onClick = {
                    onDismiss()
                    onClickListeners[index].invoke()
                }
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the preview

```
@Preview
@Composable
fun PreviewListItemPopupMenu() {
    var expanded by remember { mutableStateOf(true) }

    ListItemPopupMenu(
        menuItems = listOf("Menu1", "Menu2"),
        onClickListeners = listOf(
            {
                // do nothing
            },
            {
                // do nothing
            }
        ),
        onDismiss = {
            expanded = false
        },
        showMenu = expanded
    )
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, this worked for me, really simple solution.